# Hibernate throws error with check column duplication: Adding Hibernate classes at runtime with metadata

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently doing a port from Apache OJB to Hibernate.  The application I'm working with requires me to build the Hibernate class mappings at runtime.  To accomplish this I'm using our proprietary metadata, and mapping the fields of each Model class to the new Hibernate classes, as we did successfully with Apache OJB.  Below I will include the relevant classes.  After mapping the classes I'm getting a check column duplication error from hibernate:  It's a null pointer, which leads me to believe that the columns aren't mapping well.
The error is thrown when the call to buildSessionFactory is initiated.
Thank you for any thoughts!

```
 The Error:
 java.lang.NullPointerException at      
 org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:723)



 The Classes:

    public class HibernateMetadataConverter implements MetadataConverter
     {
    public static Configuration cfg = 
            HibernateConfigurator.getInstance()
                .setProperty("default_entity_mode", "dynamic-   map");
    public int count = 0;

    Mappings mappings = cfg.createMappings();


      public void convert(Table table, Map<Class<?>, Table> tables)
      {
         // First setup the table 
         org.hibernate.mapping.Table hibTable = 
                mappings.addTable("montecarlo", null, table.getObjectType().getName(),
                        null, false);

         hibTable.setName(table.getObjectType().getName());
         hibTable.setSchema("montecarlo");
         mappings.addTableBinding(hibTable.getSchema(), null,
                 hibTable.getName(), hibTable.getName(), null);
         Property property;
         SimpleValue value;

         // Create PersistentClass with rootClass, sub of  PersistentClass
         RootClass clazz = new RootClass();
         clazz.setEntityName(hibTable.getName());
         clazz.setJpaEntityName(table.getObjectType().getName());
         clazz.setLazy(true);
         clazz.setTable(hibTable);
         clazz.setNodeName(hibTable.getName());

         //Iterate metadata columns and create hibernate objects
         for (Column f : table.getColumns()) 
         {
            // System.out.println("ojb table name is " +  table.getName() + "\n");
            /* String tableFields = table.toString();
             if (tableFields.contains("stored")) {
                 System.out.println("skipping table stored in other table");
             }
             else 
             {
             */

             if (table.getObjectType().getName().equals("gov.lanl.ldrd.montecarlo.model.Worker")
                     && count == 0) {
                     System.out.println(table.toString());
                     count = 1;
             }


                 org.hibernate.mapping.Column col =
                         new org.hibernate.mapping.Column();

                 col.setName(f.getColumnName());

                 org.hibernate.mapping.Column typeCol = processColumn(col, f);

                 col.setSqlType(typeCol.getSqlType());
                 col.setSqlTypeCode(typeCol.getSqlTypeCode());
                 value = new SimpleValue(mappings, hibTable);

                 Class<?> javaType;
                 if (col.getSqlTypeCode() != null) 
                 {
                     javaType =  setDefaultJavaType(col.getSqlTypeCode());
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     System.out.println("sqlCodeType is null!");
                     javaType = null;
                 }

                 String typeName;
                 if (javaType != null) 
                 {
                    typeName = setHibernateType(javaType, col.getSqlTypeCode());
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     col.setNullable(true);
                     System.out.println( " Column is " + col.getName());
                     typeName = null;
                 }
                 value.setTypeName(typeName);
                 value.setTable(hibTable);
                 value.addColumn(col);



                 if (f.isPrimaryKey()) 
                 {
                     PrimaryKey pk = new PrimaryKey();
                     pk.setName(f.getColumnName());
                     pk.setTable(hibTable);
                     pk.addColumn(col);

                     hibTable.setIdentifierValue(value);

                     hibTable.setPrimaryKey(pk);
                 }


                 property = new Property();
                 property.setName(col.getName());
                 property.setValue(value);
                 property.setPersistentClass(clazz);


                      property.setNodeName(table.getObjectType().getName());


                 clazz.addProperty(property);
                 mappings.addColumnBinding(property.getName(),  
                                          col, hibTable);



    }


         System.out.println("PersistentClass is " +   
                   clazz.getEntityName());
         mappings.addClass(clazz);
         mappings.addImport(clazz.getEntityName(), 
                   clazz.getEntityName());
         cfg.addAnnotatedClass(clazz.getClass());
         cfg.buildMapping();
  }


 public org.hibernate.mapping.Column processColumn  
 (org.hibernate.mapping.Column col, 
          Column ojbColumn) {

      if (ojbColumn.getJDBCType().equals("VARCHAR"))
         {
              col.setSqlType(ojbColumn.getJDBCType());
              col.setSqlTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR);

         }
         else if (ojbColumn.getJDBCType().equals("BIGINT"))
         { 
             col.setSqlType(ojbColumn.getJDBCType());
             col.setSqlTypeCode(Types.BIGINT);
         }
         else if (ojbColumn.getJDBCType().equals("INTEGER"))
         {
             col.setSqlType(ojbColumn.getJDBCType());
             col.setSqlTypeCode(Types.INTEGER);
         }
         else if (ojbColumn.getJDBCType().equals("DOUBLE"))
         {
             col.setSqlType(ojbColumn.getJDBCType());
             col.setSqlTypeCode(Types.DOUBLE);
         }
         else if (ojbColumn.getJDBCType().equals("BIT"))
         {
             col.setSqlType(ojbColumn.getJDBCType());
             col.setSqlTypeCode(Types.BOOLEAN);
         }

      return col;
  }

        public static Class<?> setDefaultJavaType(int jdbcType) {
            switch (jdbcType) {
                case Types.BIGINT:
                    return Long.class;
                case Types.BIT:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case Types.BOOLEAN:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case Types.CHAR:
                    return String.class;
                case Types.VARCHAR:
                    return String.class;
                case Types.DATE:
                    return Date.class;
                case Types.TIME:
                    return Time.class;
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    return Timestamp.class;
                case Types.DECIMAL:
                    return BigDecimal.class;
                case Types.NUMERIC:
                    return BigDecimal.class;
                case Types.DOUBLE:
                    return Double.class;
                case Types.REAL:
                    return Double.class;
                case Types.FLOAT:
                    return Float.class;
                case Types.INTEGER:
                    return Integer.class;
                case Types.SMALLINT:
                    return Short.class;
                case Types.TINYINT:
                    return Byte.class;
                case Types.BINARY:
                    return byte[].class;
                case Types.BLOB:
                    return java.sql.Blob.class;
                case Types.CLOB:
                    return java.sql.Blob.class;
                case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
                    return byte[].class;
                case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                    return java.lang.String.class;
                case Types.VARBINARY:
                    return byte[].class;
                case Types.ARRAY:
                    return java.sql.Array.class;
                case Types.DATALINK:
                    return java.net.URL.class;
                case Types.DISTINCT:
                case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
                    return String.class;
                case Types.NULL:
                case Types.OTHER:
                case Types.REF:
                    return java.sql.Ref.class;
                case Types.STRUCT:
                    return java.sql.Struct.class;
                default:
                        System.out.println("Unsupported jdbc   

                                        type: {} " + jdbcType);
                        return null;
            }
        }

        public static String setHibernateType(Class<?> javaType, int 
                    sqlTypeCode) {
            String typeName;
            int jdbcTypeCode;
            jdbcTypeCode = sqlTypeCode;

            if (javaType == null) {
                typeName = "TypeName Error";
                return typeName;
            }
            if (javaType == Long.class) {
                return typeName = LongType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Short.class) {
                return typeName = ShortType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Integer.class) {
                return typeName = 
                                 IntegerType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Byte.class) {
                return typeName = ByteType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Float.class) {
                return typeName = FloatType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Double.class) {
                return typeName = DoubleType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == Character.class) {
                return typeName = 
                                 CharacterType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == String.class) {
                return typeName = StringType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if 
                           (java.util.Date.class.isAssignableFrom(javaType)) {
                switch (jdbcTypeCode) {
                case Types.DATE:
                    typeName = DateType.INSTANCE.getName();
                    break;
                case Types.TIME:
                    typeName = TimeType.INSTANCE.getName();
                    break;
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    typeName = 
                            TimestampType.INSTANCE.getName();
                    break;
                default:
                    typeName = null;
                }
                return typeName;
            } else if (javaType == Boolean.class) {
                if (jdbcTypeCode == Types.BIT || jdbcTypeCode == 
                                 Types.BOOLEAN) {
                    return typeName = 
                                         BooleanType.INSTANCE.getName();
                } else if (jdbcTypeCode == Types.NUMERIC || 
                                           jdbcTypeCode == Types.DECIMAL) {
                    return typeName = 
                                      NumericBooleanType.INSTANCE.getName();
                } else if (jdbcTypeCode == Types.CHAR || 
                                           jdbcTypeCode == Types.VARCHAR) {
                    return typeName = 
                                         StringType.INSTANCE.getName();
                } else {
                    return typeName = null;
                } 
            } else if (javaType == BigDecimal.class) {
                return typeName = 
                                 BigDecimalType.INSTANCE.getName();
            } else if (javaType == BigInteger.class) {
                return typeName = 
                                 BigIntegerType.INSTANCE.getName();
            }  else if (javaType == byte[].class) {
                return typeName = BlobType.INSTANCE.getName();
            }
            return typeName = null;
        }

 }


 --------------------------------------------

 public class HibernateConfigurator {

     private static Configuration hibConfig;


     protected HibernateConfigurator() {}

     public static Configuration getInstance() 
     {
    if (hibConfig == null) 
    {
        hibConfig = new Configuration();
        hibConfig.configure();
    }
    return hibConfig;
}



 }
 --------------------------------------------

 public class SessionFactoryUtil 
 {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory()
    throws HibernateException 
{
    try 
    {
        Configuration configuration =  
                         HibernateConfigurator.getInstance();
        configuration.configure();
        //configuration.buildMappings();

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .buildServiceRegistry();

        //new Exception().printStackTrace();

        sessionFactory =   
                         configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    } catch (HibernateException e){ e.printStackTrace();}

    return sessionFactory;
}

public static SessionFactory getInstance() 
{
    return configureSessionFactory();
}

public static void close() 
{
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}


   }
```

Comment: So... Much... Code... :). Can you post the relevant parts of your stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:723)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:479)
 at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1303)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1761)
 at gov.lanl.mcf.server.persistence.hibernate.SessionFactoryUtil.configureSessionFactory(SessionFactoryUtil.java:32)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out why i'm getting this checkColumnDuplication Error:

In my code we can see that while I was indeed setting an identifier value for the class, I was also setting that identifier value as a property.  This in effect was mapping the same column twice.  A column can be mapped to a property or an identifier value(primaryKey), it can't be both.